# How to run an AutoIt script and call a function from it?

Tags: function, call, autoit

CONVERTER.au3 converts webp to png using dwebp:

```
Convert()

Func Convert()
    $hSearch = FileFindFirstFile(@ScriptDir & "\*.webp")
    $sFileName = FileFindNextFile($hSearch)
    $Split = StringSplit($sFileName, ".")

    ;~ MsgBox(0,'',$Split[1])

    Run("dwebp.exe " & $sFilename & " -o " & $Split[1] & ".png")
EndFunc

Func Troubleshoot()
    Convert()
    Local $hSearch
    If $hSearch = -1 Then
        $desktopCON = "supported"
    Else
        $desktopCON = "unsupported"
    EndIf
    FileClose($hSearch)
    Exit
EndFunc
```

I need to run CONVERTER.au3 and call a specific function from it. I tried this but doesn't seem to work:

```
Run("D:\SCRIPT\NEW\CONVERTER.au3 Call(Convert)")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Parameters](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/running.htm) are referenced with the `$CmdLine` array. The first element (`$CmdLine[0]` is the number of parameters, `$CmdLine[1]` is the first parameter, etc.).

```
If $CmdLine[0] = 0 Then  ; standard behavour for no params
    Convert()
    Exit
EndIf

If $CmdLine[1] = "convert" Then ; param is "convert"
    Convert()
    Exit
EndIf

If $CmdLine[1] = "troubleshoot" Then ; param is "troubleshoot"
    Troubleshoot()
    Exit
EndIf

MsgBox(0, "ERRROR", "undefined function: " & $CmdLine[1])

Func Convert()
    MsgBox(0, "", "your converting code here")
EndFunc   ;==>Convert

Func Troubleshoot()
    MsgBox(0, "", "your troubleshooting code here")
EndFunc   ;==>Troubleshoot
```

Execute it from AutoIt with `Run('"Converter.au3" foobar')`
or from the Windows Command line with just `converter.au3 troubleshoot`

If no parameter is given, it executes a default function (or whatever you want it to do).